Do validators get slashed if they go down?
We have some SOL staked with a validator and are wondering what will happen if the validator suddenly dies?
Are there rules they have to apply or is it the validator himself that needs to set up some rules for that. Or will we lose our SOL?

You will not. Solana does not currently implement automatic slashing. This means if your validator goes down or is otherwise delinquent, all that will happen is that you will not earn rewards for the time in which your validator isn't validating.
In theory, Solana supports social slashing by where 66% of stake weighted nodes could run a version that punishes a certain malicious node, but in practice this has never happened before.
You can also check Stakewiz where you can see that most nodes have at least a little bit of downtime and were fine.
